# Create SharePoint IF function Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-workflow

I am trying to update the date in a column based on the information contained in another column.  I know it will be an "IF" function, but I am not getting the formula correct.
I need to update the due date column by adding the time based from the frequency columnn(week, day, month, etc...) to the completion date column....please help!

Answer (score 0):

I would not use the Designer inside Visual Studio to handle an If-Clause. Reason: I didn't figure out how to use this and from other things lieke the While-Activity I read that this is much slower than a coded one.
For some handsome looking I would add "CodeActivity" and link/ invoke my method to this. Inside this method you could use
`string frequency = workflowProperties.Item["name of other column"].ToString();

    string oldDate = workflowProperties.Item["name of updating column"].ToString();

    DateTime newDate = Convert.ToDateTime(oldDate);

    if (String.Equals(frequency, "weekly", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))

        {

          <your code like:> workflowProperties.Item["name of updating column"] = newDate.AddDays(7);

     }

    else if (...)

    or use switch (frequency){}`

Remind that workflowProperties.Item refers everytime to selected Item. Because this is a global variable inside your workflow, you can access to it from every method. If you don't understand this example, be free to ask.

Shegit